# Send mail to multiple recipients in Yiimailmessage

Tags: php, email, yii

I wanna send email to multiple recipients at a time without adding `cc` and only by `to` using `YiimailMessege` extension.Is it possible any suggestions will be appreciated.I have tried by adding `cc` and it works but I dont wanna add `cc`.my code looks like this

```
        $message = new YiiMailMessage;
        $message->view =$model->viewName;
        $message->subject    = $model->subject;
        $params  = array('myMail'=>$model->object1);
        $message->setBody($params,'text/html');
        $message->addTo($model->to);
        $message->AddCC($model->from);
        $message->from = $model->from;
        $message->cc=array($model->senderEmail,$model->additionalEmail);
        $message->Replyto = $model->from;
        Yii::app()->mail->send($message);
```

and how it would possible by `to` using `YiimailMessege` extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$message = new YiiMailMessage;
$message->subject    = $model->subject;
$message->view =$model->viewName;
$message->from = $model->from;
$message->setBody($params,'text/html');
$params  = array('myMail'=>$model->object1);
foreach($emails as $email) {
    $message->addTo($model->to);
    Yii::app()->mail->send($message);
}
```

Comment: Thq for reply ..I will try

Comment: why did you use foreach in above code...please will u explain

Comment: foreach means iterate each item over array. In this case I have array of emails like $emails = ['example@site.com', 'test@test.com']. And I get each email by $email variable

Comment: but you didnt use the variable $email in foreach ..that is I am asking about

Comment: Oh, yes. I had mistake. There should be $message->addTo($email);

Comment: thank you worked ur code by small change..I used `Yii::app()->mail->send()` after `foreach` and works like charm..thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
$message->addTo(array('john@example.com','jane@example.com'));
```

Did you Try this case

Comment: Thq for reply ..I will try

Answer (score 1):

protected function _sendOrderDetailMail($orderId)
{
   $model = $this->loadModel($orderId);

$message = new YiiMailMessage;

$message->view  = 'orderdetail';

$message->setBody(array('orderId'=>$orderId, 'model'=>$model), 'text/html');

$message->subject = 'New Order Placed - '.$orderId;

$message->addTo(Yii::app()->params['adminEmail']);

```
           //  emails to keep in cc

           $emails = array('abc@example.com','abc1@example.com');

           foreach($emails as $value){

                      $message->addCC(trim($value));  

           }
```

Yii::app()->mail->send($message);
  }

Email This

Comment: Thank you for answer .. I have tried using cc as I mentioned in the question..thank you for response